# Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

Help! please, I'm trying to add Mysql injection to my code:

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconn,$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO `T`(`ID`,`FName`, `LName`, `Gender`, `Agreement`,`Photo`,`Photo_name`) VALUES  ('$id','$fname','$lname','$Gender','$radios','$image','$image_name')"))
{
        /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);


}
```

I'm getting this warning

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\Ex\insert-data.php on line 30
>       Call Stack
>       #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>       1   0.0005  142320  {main}( )   ..\insert-data.php:0
>       2   0.1655  294232  mysqli_stmt_bind_param ( )  ..\insert-data.php:30

line 30 is :

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
```

Is there any way to fix that? 
I tried this type  `$mysqli->prepare`, but it didn't work.

Any idea?, Thanks for any help.

Comment: you're not binding anything. Here, read up on it http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: exactly, no binds at all, and vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) to boot...

Comment: simple fix => `(?,'$fname', ...`

Comment: As I said before, i tried this ..the same you gave me yesterday... I'm getting more errors,,,any way thank you

Comment: See these are the errors after i changed the way you said:               Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\wamp\www\Ex\insert-data.php on line 27
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 142832 {main}( ) ..\insert-data.php:0

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Ex\insert-data.php on line 27
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 142832 {main}( ) ..\insert-data.php:0

Comment: if your id column is auto_increment, then that won't work.

Comment: you'll need to post your full code then, including DB connection while replacing credentials with fake ones.

Comment: Yes ,it is auto_increment

Comment: It seems that i need to change the whole connect.php that i wrote yesterday

Comment: bind on another variable instead. You can then do `('','$BINDED_fname', ...` the first `''` would be the empty value for the ID column, which is valid. Each binded value needs `?` for each one(s) as per the manual states http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are willing to use PDO instead of mysqli.

Your database connection should look like this:

**DB.php**

```
 <?php
   $host   = 'localhost';
   $dbname = 'Example';
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Example', $username,
   $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


   ?>
```

Prepared Statements:

**file.php**

```
   <?php
     //Example prepared statement with INSERT
   $reply = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reply (user_name, 
    receipient, comment, comment_id, user_image) VALUES  
      (:username,:receipient,:commentt,:commentid,:userimage)");

    $reply->bindParam(":username", $user3_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $reply->bindParam(":receipient", $user2_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $reply->bindParam(":commentt", $comment2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $reply->bindParam(":commentid", $c_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $reply->bindParam(":userimage", $u_image, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $reply->execute();

       ?>
```

FOR MYSQLI

**db.php**

```
 <?php

  $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dbname");
  ?>
```

**file.php**

```
    <?php
     $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO reply (user_name, 
    receipient, comment, user_image) VALUES  
      (?,?,?,?)");
     $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $receipient,$commentt,$userimage);

      $stmt->execute();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks chris94 ,,,is there any chance to use mysqli instead of PDO ....Because i used mysqli

Comment: @Judy, i've updated my answer. Notice that there are four strings "iiii" and four "????" due to the fact that i'm trying to pass four variables into the insert query.

Comment: `bind_param('iiii',` most of which stand at being strings, therefore `s`. - `i`'s will fail.

Comment: I tried this,but i'm getting :   Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_prepare()

Comment: @Judy which sub-version of PHP 5? 5.2, .3, .4, .5.. other?

Comment: @Judy shouldn't be a problem. Make sure your connection variable matches what's in the query. Change respectively.

Comment: $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconn,$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO `T`(`FName`, `LName`, `Gender`, `Agreement`,`Photo`,`Photo_name`) VALUES  ('$fname','$lname','$Gender','$radios','$image','$image_name')");
     $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $fname,$lname,$Gender,$radios,$image,$image_name);

      $stmt->execute();

Comment: @Fred  I wrote $mysqli->prepare the same way in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. However, The results : Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli , Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object ..this is the connection code :  $dbconn = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name") or die("Error".mysqli_error($dbconn));

Comment: @Judy all these `('$fname','$lname','$Gender','$radios','$image','$image_name')` need to be replaced by `?` and the same number for them, when using prepared statements. from the manual `if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {`

Comment: @Judy, you cant $mysqli->prepare without having a $mysqli connection to your database. look at my answer, notice the variable "$db" in db.php is used in the prepare statement in file.php. ie "$db->prepare". so if you're going to use $mysqli->prepare make sure you have set up your database connection in $mysqli.

Comment: @Judy, follow my example carefully, change the variables and values to match yours, and you wont have a problem.

Comment: Thank you @chris94 ...I wrote this :                                                 $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sqlinsert="INSERT INTO `T`(`FName`, `LName`, `Gender`, `Agreement`,`Photo`,`Photo_name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)");
 $stmt->bind_param('s',$fname);
       $stmt->execute();                                                                                       $dbconn is instead of $mysql in your code ...I'm getting this :        Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object   ....is there anything wrong in my code?....thanks a lot

Comment: @Judy, Your sql statement is probably false, you have made some errors, remove the extra "," at the end of "(?,?,?,?,?,?)," it should be "(?,?,?,?,?,?)". also remove $sqlinsert, i dont see any need for it, as the statement is already in the variable $stmt.

Comment: @Judy, try my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$fname = $_POST['first'];//should be the name attribute used in your form
$lname = $_POST['last'];
$gender = $_POST['gen'];
$agreement = $_POST['agree'];
$photo = $_POST['pic'];
$p_name = $_POST['pic_name'];

$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO T(FName, LName, Gender,
Agreement,Photo,Photo_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 

$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$fname,$lname,$gender,$agreement,$photo,$p_name);

$stmt->execute();

 ?>
```